# converting a semi-structured excel database into a sharepoint database

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel, database, content-and-structure

Our company has an excel customer-record cheat sheet. we're trying to integrate that cheat sheet into SharePoint. However, the sheets in the excel cheat sheet are not relational structured data. Some cell values for example, link you to other sheets in the workbook or to other tables as a way to navigate the cheat sheet faster. Is there a way to fully integrate the functionality of this excel workbook cheat sheet into SharePoint?

I could only import the structured tables into SharePoint lists, but the other aspects of the workbook such as the cell navigation, I'm stuck at and would appreciate any help on where to start with implementing this. Or should I just create a bunch of quick links that lead to the tables in the lists?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports importing "Tables" from spreadsheets to new SharePoint lists. You can import structured tables from your Excel customer-record cheat sheet into SharePoint lists. However, the other aspects of the workbook, such as cell navigation, cannot be fully integrated into SharePoint. One option could be to create a bunch of quick links that lead to the tables in the lists.